# Extracting specific percentage of data in R

Tags: r, percentage

Having a vector of sorted integers, I want to extract 10 percent of data from each extreme. For instance having integers from 1 to 100, I want to take 10 percent from left tail of data (1:10) and 10 percent from right tail of data (91:100). I can do it by first sorting data and then dividing into 100 and extracting first and last part. But, I wanted to know if R has a built function for it.

Thanks!

Comment: `head(1:100, .1 * length(1:100)); tail(1:100, .1 * length(1:100))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a careful use of `quantile` and `sample`?`

```
xx <- rnorm(1e3)
thresh <- quantile(xx, c(.1, .9))

left <- xx[xx <= thresh[[1]]]
left <- sample(left, length(left) %/% 10)

right <- xx[xx >= thresh[[2]]]
right <- sample(right, length(right) %/% 10)
```

Comment: I don't think you need those steps with `sample`.

Comment: Yeah I think the OP just wants the 10% of data at each tail, not a random sample _of_ those.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to be the sure that there is no single built in function to extract them.